# X -config hangs and doesn't produce an xorg.conf

Tags: linux, x11, xorg

I am trying to generate an `xorg.conf` file for my current configuration. I am using `X -config xorg.conf`, but it doesn't produce a file.

Here is the output:

```
    # X -config  xorg.conf.new

X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
Current Operating System: Linux mapcrunch.localdomain 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cl-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cl/root rd.lvm.lv=cl/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Build Date: 06 November 2016  12:43:39AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.17.2-22.el7
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 17 19:21:55 2017
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
pci id for fd 12: 102b:0534, driver (null)
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
```

It then hangs and never returns to prompt.

[edit] [Last comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386841/x-config-hangs-and-doesnt-produce-an-xorg-conf#comment688747_386889) by original poster:

> I did end up realizing that I was using the wrong command then ran
>   into a bound kernel driver error. I then had to blacklist the driver
>   for some reason in order to get the xorg.conf file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch to the console mode , then stop your display manager.

To generate the `xorg.conf.new` file you should use the `Xorg -configure` command, it will be located under `/root/xorg.conf.new`

Move the `/root/xorg.conf.new` to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Finally start your display manager.

[Debian-WIKI : What if I do not have an xorg config file?](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg#What_if_I_do_not_have_an_xorg_config_file.3F)

Answer (score 4):

`Xorg -config` doesn't show you your X configuration, it is used to start an X server with an alternate one. You got the suspension, because your X server probably started, somewhere on an alternate console.

Try `Xorg --configure`. It autodetects the hardware and dumps the generated X configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I did end up realizing that I was using the wrong command then ran into a bound kernel driver error. I then had to blacklist the driver for some reason in order to get the xorg.conf file.